# 3D mapping of focused ultrasound signal

Tags: python, graph, 3d, mapping, field

I have a 3D stage which carries a sensor and measures Ultrasonic signals in 3D space at specified points. What would be the best way of visualizing this data in python?

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be interpreted in two ways:

1) What is a good python tool for drawing such a visualization?
2) What is a good visualization for such data?

I'll tackle both:
1) [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) looks sufficient.
2) I think a a 3D scatter plot is a good visualization for such data. This is because you can capture 4 dimensions of data: x,y,z and colour. Also, x,y,z closely resemble space. If it's possible to change the plots' sizes, then you have a 5th dimension.